# Error while trying to login in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I am facing an error on login if I enter wrong credentials. Error is: `500-An error has occurred`. When I enter wrong username and password rather then displaying error message on joomla administrator login page, it redirects me to new page which shows me the above error.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Check your error log to see what the actual error was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your error log for any clues on where it may be happening. This can be caused by a few items. If you have SEF and Attach Suffix enabled for URL Rewritting you need to uncomment the following in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Second if you can change folder permission to `775` for the following folders:

> cache, logs, tmp & administrator/cache

then go to: `configuration.php`

find code:

```
$log_path = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$tmp_path = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX';
```

and change code into:

```
$log_path = './logs';
$tmp_path = './tmp';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

Change your folder permission `777`. As well under folders `cache`, `logs`, `tmp` and `administrator/cache`. Inside `configration.php` find code:

```
$log_path = ' something ';
$tmp_path = ' something ';
```

change code

```
$log_path = './logs';
$tmp_path = './tmp';
```

This should help solve your problem.

Comment: @Nikola thanks for editing for me. Forgot about greying out the coding part:)

Comment: @Nikola: Thanks a lot buddy. It works just changing the path only. I understand it fetch local path only. Once again thanks !

Comment: @manpreet: actually, the credit goes to Ryan Fung as he answered your question. I merely edited his code to be better formated.

Comment: @Nikola Doesn't matter man. I am here to help, I don't care about getting any credit.

Answer (score 0):

Everywhere on Joomla forums suggested to set rights on log files and dirs. This not worked for me at all. But I followed execution code and found that 500 server error on client (on my site login process is called by mootools ajax) is followed by displaying 404 error page by Joomla, called in `/joomla/error/error.php` `customErrorPage` method. I don't know why 404 page echoed on wrong credentials. So I just set not to call `customErrorPage` in `/plugins/system/logout/logout.php`, by putting `if ($error->getCode() == 102001) return;` line before it. '102001' is the 'Wrong credentials' error. So this means 'do not display 404 error when wrong credentials are used'. May be it is not best solution and its site-dependent and I will found later a best one. But hope this could help someone.